# Verifying if package is installed before downloading it in PUPPET

Tags: puppet

That is my manifest code which download, install and remove installer on a host.

```
class googlechrome_2 {

  package { 'GoogleChrome':
    ensure => installed,
    source => 'C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
    install_options => ['/qn'],
    require => File['GoogleChromeMsi'],
  }

  file { 'GoogleChromeMsi':
    ensure => file,
    path => 'C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
    source => 'puppet:///files/production/ChromeSetup.msi',
  }

  exec { 'msi_removing':
    command => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c del C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
  }

}
```

In this case my windows host always download chromesetup.msi regardless if google chrome already installed or not. How can I realize kind of "if condition" here to avoid downloading msi package each time in case if this package already installed?

Comment: You could either attempt to use the remote source with the package provider if that is allowed, or remove the resource that removes the `msi` afterwards.

Comment: As you can see I already realized exec source which delete previously downloaded package. It works in any cases, but I mean useless downloading when it's not needed, especially on many hosts simultaneously. @MattSchuchard

Comment: As for remote source I'm not sure if it's possible using package source from a win client to a linux puppet server.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case my windows host always download chromesetup.msi regardless if google chrome already installed or not.

Yes.  Having the `File` resource in the node's catalog specifies that the file should be managed.  Therefore, if it is not initially in the target state then Puppet will attempt to fix that.

By managing the file present but also including an `Exec` that removes the file, you ensure that the target node cannot achieve a stable state.

> How can I realize kind of "if condition" here to avoid downloading msi package each time in case if this package already installed?

**Simplest option:** don't remove the installer.

**Variation:** Put the installer in an accessible network folder, so that you not only don't remove it, but you also don't install it.

**If you really want a conditional:** then it should be based on a [custom fact](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/fact_overview.html) that reports on the installation status of the package in question.  You then use a Puppet `if` statement to control the contents of the node's catalog appropriately.  Something along these lines, for example:

```
  package { 'GoogleChrome':
    ensure          => 'installed',
    source          => 'C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
    install_options => ['/qn'],
    # relationhip with File['GoogleChromeMsi'] now declared on the other end
  }

  if $facts['chrome_is_installed'] {
    file { 'GoogleChromeMsi':
      ensure => 'absent',
      path   => 'C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
    }
  } else {
    file { 'GoogleChromeMsi':
      ensure => 'file',
      path   => 'C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
      source => 'puppet:///files/production/ChromeSetup.msi',
      before => Package['GoogleChrome'],
    }

    exec { 'msi_removing':
      command => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c del C:\Soft\ChromeSetup.msi',
      require => Package['GoogleChrome'],
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May be do you have any ideas or experience how it should be realized/implemented (instead of my solution) for the case with a windows host where you have to deploy application, but also have to manage installer files (I mean downloading/deleting). Of course a network shared folder should be a solution (I hope), but may be there are some "best practices"?

Comment: @TemaShaposhnikov, I already gave you such a recommendation, with example manifest code.  You would need to complement that with an implementation of the required custom fact, as described.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using network shared folder in the package source:

```
class googlechrome_smb {
  package { 'Google Chrome':
    ensure => installed,
    source => '\\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\winfiles\ChromeSetup.msi',
    install_options => ['/qn'],
  }
}
```